# Не открывается переконвертированный в .exe из pyqt5 файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Я создаю приложение на pyqt5 когда сделал не большую часть работы захотел перекинуть в exe формат использовал pyinstaller и когда переконвертировал попытался открыть но ни чего не работает. Просто на время открывается cmd и закрывается, а само приложения с интерфейсом не открывается!
Помогите плиз!!!
Вот код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from food import Ui_MainWindow
import subprocess
a=1

class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.past)


    def past(self):
        global a
        a += 1
        print(a)
        self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(a)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

food.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'food.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.6
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(849, 600)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
"    font-size:14px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:silver;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QWidget {\n"
"    background-color:white;\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 111, 41))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"    background-color:gray;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:silver;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"    background-color:white;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 30, 241, 21))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
"    font-size:14px;\n"
"}")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 30, 91, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 30, 211, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(720, 30, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.dateEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 0, 110, 22))
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName("dateEdit")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 60, 731, 481))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(7)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setText("Имя ученика")
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 849, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.tableWidget.doItemsLayout)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить ученика"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Льгота для малообеспеченой семьи:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Льгота для обеспеченой семьи: "))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пн"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вт"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ср"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Чт"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пт"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Остаток(бюджет)"))
```

Comment: опубликуйте модуль `food.py`

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonicam это stackoverflow на русском, Поэтому комментарии нужно оставлять на русском языке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модули, **в том виде, что вы опубликовали** у меня компилируются и запускаются.

**pyinstaller -c -F pyinstaller_1043872.py**

```
280 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
280 INFO: Python: 3.7.3
280 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
...
73060 INFO: Appending archive to EXE D:\_Qt\__Qt\dist\pyinstaller_1043872.exe
73296 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какие у вас версии `Python`, `PyInstaller`, `Platform` ?

---

Также хочу дать вам совет:

1. Плохая практика использовать глобальные переменные, особенно с `PyQt`.
2. Старайтесь использовать наименование переменный, классов, методов - согласно рекомендаций Pythonа.

Ваш main.py может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
#import subprocess
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from food import Ui_MainWindow


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, rows):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self.rows = rows
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.set_row_count)

    def set_row_count(self):
        self.rows += 1
        print(self.rows)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.rows)


number_rows = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow(number_rows)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: python - 3.5.1 pyinstaller - 3.5 Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1